# OWIN vs Windows Identity Foundation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wif, owin

I have an ASP.NET MVC that was originally built using WIF as the underlying identity management technology. As I keep upgrading our app to newer MVC technology, it seems like Microsoft is moving in a different direction and building MVC on top of OWIN which includes middleware for a lot of the things that WIF provides. I know that a lot of WIF was integrated directly with .NET 4. Does the OWIN identity middleware use WIF underneath? Is OWIN something I should move everything over to eventually to just use that middleware for the identity stuff instead of WIF?

Comment: OWIN is a standard and middleware from Microsoft (like Katana) is the Microsoft implementation of OWIN. You'll have to look at the individual middleware to see what it supports. Also, I would wait until more info about vNext comes out because it is very similar.\

Comment: One has very little to do with another. OWIN is a base-level tech intended to allow open and modular interaction between servers and web applications. You can implement virtually anything on top of it.